# Can't update mkdirp to Istalling Express-generator

Tags: node.js, express, npm, command, express-generator

I'm facing an issue while installing express-generator using this commande  :

```
npm install -g express-generator
```

after executing it I get this error :

> npm WARN deprecated mkdirp@0.5.1: Legacy versions of mkdirp are no longer supported. Please update to mkdirp 1.x. (Note that the API surface has changed to use Promises in 1.x.)